# Apple Business Chat Sandbox not loading

Tags: ios, imessage, apple-business-chat

I'm seeing the following while trying to sign into Apple Chat Business Sandbox for the first time:

[image]

The spinner keeps spinning without any response...

This is happening in both Safari and Chrome browsers.

I'm on [image: High Sierra] and [image: Chrome 73]

What's missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to the usual promotional bruhaha made by Apple for a [couple](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GgwbNHL1OA8) of years [in a row](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/232/) for its **Apple Business Chat Sandbox** as a [great tool for developers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GgwbNHL1OA8), this seems to be yet another of their software duds.

After a lot (over a month) of back and forth emailing Apple support and experiencing loads of gaslighting and obfuscating by Apple folks of the real state of things, i.e:

[image]

I finally asked them directly:

[image]

Here's Apple's response:

[image]

Perhaps this will serve as a warning for someone looking to implement Apple Business Chat to take their much ballyhooed products with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Apple sandbox page is gone.

You still have the documentation at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/businesschat/exploring_business_chat

And the current sandbox env link : https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/login?isESAEnabled=false&appIdKey=e096fbe1d4b3913a4fa19b9f21a9ad4e58ab71dc3963c5b72a439fb539b6bea6&rv=2

You’ll need a device running iOS 11.3 or later to use the Business Chat Sandbox.

On your iOS device, sign in to Messages using your Apple ID. Go to Settings > Messages > Send & Receive > Apple ID.

Sign in to Business Chat Sandbox with the Apple ID you are using for Messages. A QR code appears the first time you log in.

Scan the QR code with the camera on your iOS device. Then follow the notification on the top to launch a Business Chat conversation with the Business Chat Sandbox.